# How to display first N posts in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm using Jekyll 2 for my blog. I'm also using [jekyll-paginate](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-paginate) to display the first 5 posts in the home page.

Now I would like to stop using jekyll-paginate, since it's polluting the sitemap with pages I don't want.

This is how my home page looks like, after removing the pagination:

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="blog-index">
  {% assign index = true %}
  {% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign content = post.content %}
    <article>
      {% include article.html %}
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This displays *all* the posts, but I only want the first 5. In Ruby you can do `.take(5)` or `.first(5)`, so I tried that, but it doesn't work.

How do I display only the 5 most recent posts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use the `limit` parameter in a `for` loop to do this:

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:5 %}
   <article>
      {% include article.html %}
    </article>
{% end %}
```

docs: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/iteration/#limit

Comment: Now in the next loop how to start posts from `index 6`